# Double summation involving complex numbers

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, summation

I have come across this complex number problem which stated as follows. 
If $\alpha=e^{\frac{2\pi i} {7}}$ and $$f(x) = A_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{20} A_k x^k$$ then find $$\sum_{r=0}^{6} f\left(\alpha^r x\right) =? $$
I then plugged in the function in the summation which I am required to find. $$\sum_{r=0}^{6} f\left(\alpha^r x\right) = 7A_0 + \sum_{r=0}^{6} \sum_{k=1}^{20} A_k x^k e^{\frac{2\pi i} {7} rk} $$ Now I am stuck. Let us call that double summation term as U. So I thought $$ U= \sum_{k=1}^{20} A_k x^k \sum_{r=0}^{6} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7} k(r)} $$ Can I write it this way? If so how can I simplify it further? Thank you in advance..

Comment: The inner sum at the end is the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: But shouldn't the outer summation be done first and then inner?

Comment: @ItiShree the inner sum depends on k and the outer sum will have term that too which depends on k. So I thought  that the outer sum be done first. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think first you should solve for $\sum_{k=1}^{20}A_kx^k$ which is clearly a GP and then solve for later.

Comment: The reason for this is when r=0,1,2...then you have to solve $\sum_{k=1}^{20}A_kx^ke^0$ +$\sum_{k=1}^{20}A_kx^ke^{\frac{2\pi}{T}k}$+...

Comment: @ItiShree Can you please put it up in the solution. I am not able to figure it out clearly.

Comment: Sure I am writing it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to commutative, associative and distributive laws we can write using $\alpha=e^{\frac{2\pi i} {7}}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^{6} f\left(\alpha^r x\right) &= 7A_0 + \sum_{r=0}^{6} \sum_{k=1}^{20} A_k x^k e^{\frac{2\pi i} {7} rk}\\
> &=7A_0+\sum_{k=1}^{20}A_k x^k\sum_{r=0}^{6}   \left(e^{\frac{2\pi i} {7} k}\right)^r\\
> &=7A_0+\sum_{k=1}^{20}A_k x^k\sum_{r=0}^{6}   \left(\alpha^k\right)^r\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We can apply the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula to the inner sum of  (1) and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^{6}   \left(\alpha^k\right)^r&=\frac{1-\left(\alpha^k\right)^7}{1-\alpha^k}\\
> &=\frac{1-e^{2\pi k i}}{1-\alpha^k}\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}
>   Since the inner sum vanishes we finally conclude 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^{6} f\left(\alpha^r x\right) &= 7A_0+\sum_{k=1}^{20}A_k x^k\cdot 0\\
> &=7A_0
> \end{align*}